# .htaccess: redirect with different subfolders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Being not 100% familiar with .htaccess files, I spent already days in fixing one tiny issue, but with a huge impact. I want to create a line in my .htaccess file, which should be something like:

```
RewriteRule ^folder1/folder2/folder3/([^.]+)/?$ /folderA/folderB/page.php?variable=$1
```

I found out that the below piece of .htaccess code seems to work:

```
RewriteRule ^folder1/([^.]+)/?$ /folderA/folderB/page.php?variable=$1
```

But by adding /folder2/folder3, the RewriteRule is not working properly anymore. These extra folders are the only difference, but I must be doing something wrong.

Is there anyone who can help me out on this? I'm really lost...

Many, many, many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Maybe another `RewriteRule` in that scope is masking this one, after you add `folder2/folder3/`?

Comment: I found the issue! :-) Invisible in my ftp, but visible within my Plesk server, I noticed there was a .htaccess listed in /folder2/. After removing that file, the line in the above described .htaccess works fine.@MichałRus, many thanks for your time and effort to have a look as well.

Comment: I've suggested that... in a way. ;) Consider answering your own question then.

Comment: Indeed, @MichałRus. First I looked in the normal .htaccess, but couldn't find it. The it was just a guess that there could be a .htaccess on another location. So yes, your guess gave the right direction :) I will answer my question

Answer (score 0):

Invisible in my ftp, but visible within my Plesk server, I noticed there was a .htaccess listed in /folder2/. After removing that file, the line in the above described .htaccess works fine.